# C++ const char* put variable/DEFINE on init

Tags: c++

I have const char* variable with vertex shader code:

```
const char* FS_source_a =
    #include "fs_a.h"
 ;
```

in fs_a.h:

```
"#version 100\n"
"varying lowp vec4 v_color;\n"
"void main(void)\n"
"{\n"
        "gl_FragColor = v_color;\n"
"}\n";
```

Now, I have some defined/static variable, and I want to put it in my shader code, like this[pseudocode]:

```
"#version "+SHADER_VERSION+"\n"
```

Well.... Is this possible somehow, or I have to concat them? I want to keep shader source code in separate file.

P.S. This is not opengl question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do what you wrote, but you can do this:

**code.c**

```
#include "code.h"
const char* FS_source_a = DEFINEDVALUE;

char FS_dest_a[1024] = {0};
sprintf(FS_dest_a, FS_source_a, 100);
```

**code.h**

```
#define DEFINEDVALUE "#version %d\n\
varying lowp vec4 v_color;\n\
void main(void)\n\
{\n\
    gl_FragColor = v_color;\n\
}\n"
```

Comment: And how to put variable there?

Comment: If it is runtime variable, you cannot define it like this, you will need to modify `FS_source_a`. See my fixed answer

Comment: Is it possible to somehow know size of FS_dest_a, without : char FS_dest_a[1024] ? And calculating number of symbols by hand.

Comment: Who is generating the SHADER_VERSION ?

Comment: Its runtime... I check installed device - and then I have version. Its slighly simlified example.

Comment: You cannot use `headers` for runtime values, you need to do the `sprintf` combo I used

Comment: I understand - its ok. I mean... How would I know what I have to put instead of 1024. This is result string size in chars, right?

Comment: I don't know how big your data is, if you want it to be dynamic, do malloc() rather than a fixed size of 1024